# Fixed Point Property

Tags: general-topology

There's a questions that asks if these spaces with the usual metric in $\mathbb{R}$ (or in $\mathbb{R^2}$) have the property of the fixed point. The spaces are

- $[0, 1]$
- $[0, 1[$
- ${{[0, 1]\times[0, 1]}\setminus{(1, 1)}}$
- ${(x, y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid x \geq 0, 0 \leq y \leq 1-x}$

I tried by arguments like compacity, but I'm not understanding how it is suppose to prove, once that we just know this sets. Is this supposed to prove the property in the own set or to any?

I'm sorry if it got confused. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By fixed point property, do mean that every continuous map from $S \rightarrow S$ on the set $S$ has a fixed point?

Comment: Yes, I think it must be that. I didn't either understood the notation very well @user762914

Answer (score 1):

Can you think of a really simple function on real numbers, that reduces the size of any non-zero real number?  You can use that function to produce a function that reduces the distance of points from $1$ in your second example and from $(1,1)$ in the third example, thus not fixing any points.

For the first example for any continuous function $f\colon[0,1]\to [0,1]$, consider $f(x)-x$.  Can it be strictly negative for all $x$ or strictly positive for all $x$?

For the final example here is a solution which uses homology.  Apologies if you have not covered this yet and this is not useful.

Given a continuous function $f$ from the space $T$ to itself, if it has no fixed points you can define $g(x,y)$ as the point of intersection of the boundary of $T$ with the half line starting at $f(x,y)$ and passing through $(x,y)$.  Then $g$ is a continuous map $T\to \partial T\cong S^1$, which fixes all points in $\partial T$.  That is if $\iota\colon \partial T\to T$ denotes the natural inclusion, then $g\iota=1_{\partial T}$.  On homology we get that the identity map is the following composition:$$\mathbb{Z}\cong H_1(S^1)\stackrel{\iota_*}\longrightarrow H_1(T)\cong 0\stackrel{g_*}\longrightarrow H_1(S^1)\cong \mathbb{Z}$$
which is impossible as $0\neq1$.

If I think of a simpler way of explaining this I will update (or maybe somebody else will do this first).

Intuitively all this is saying is that $g$ fixes the boundary of the triangle.  If you take the boundary of the triangle and gradually shrink it towards the center, its image under $g$ will start off going round the boundary once, but at some point suddenly jump to going round $0$ times, which is impossible.  It should be intuitively clear that this argument works, though to write it out formally you need the machinery above.